# Alternate way for override method in Interface in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, overriding, radix

I'm working on a project that needs to replace concrete class with Interface. Below is the concrete class and its inheritance class

```
public class CarRepository 
{
    private string _model;
    private string _colour;

    public CarRepository(string model, string colour) {
        _model = model;
        _colour = colour
    }

    public string Get(GUID id)
    {
        return id.ToString();
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special) {
        special = special.AddFields(Rego, ModelNumber)
    }
}

public class BigCarRepository : CarRepository 
{
    public class BigCarRepository(string model, string colour) 
    : base(model, colour)

    protected override void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special) {
        special = special.AddFields(SpecialOffer, OptionPack)
    }
}
```

I want to replace the inheritance of a concrete class for `BigCarRepository` from `CarRepository` with an interface (i.e. `ICarRepository`). Thus I created an interface and replacing the concrete class but couldn't find a way to address the override method. I have created the interface below and modified my concrete classes and the inheritance but stuck at the override method.

```
public interface ICarRepository 
{
     string Get(string id);
}

public class CarRepository : ICarRepository
{
    private string _model;
    private string _colour;

    public CarRepository(string model, string colour) {
        _model = model;
        _colour = colour
    }

    public string Get(GUID id)
    {
        return id.ToString();
    }

    protected virtual void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special) {
        special = special.AddFields(Rego, ModelNumber)
    }
}

public class BigCarRepository : ICarRepository 
{
    public ICarRepository _carRepository { get; set; }

    public BigCarRepository(ICarRepository carRepository) 
    {
        _carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    public string Get (string id) 
    {
        return _carRepository.Get(id);
    }

    **protected override void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special) {
        special = special.AddFields(SpecialOffer, OptionPack)
    }**
}
```

Comment: If you want to invoke member inside `CarRepository` then you have to inherit `BigCarRepository` from `CarRepository` with its interface compulsory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

If you need to make an abstraction of CarRepository. You did well by extracting the interface. You also need to add all methods that you want your derived classes to implement.

```
        public interface ICarRepository 
        {
             string Get(string id);
             void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special);
        }

 public class BigCarRepository : ICarRepository 
        {
            public ICarRepository _carRepository { get; set; }

            public BigCarRepository(ICarRepository carRepository) 
            {
                _carRepository = carRepository;
            }

            public string Get (string id) 
            {
                return _carRepository.Get(id);
            }

            public void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special) {

                special = special.AddFields(SpecialOffer, OptionPack);
            }
        }
```

If this is what you want, you're fine.

In my previous answer, i suggested that you might need to reuse some logic of base class CarRepository , but still wanted to force BigCarRepository to implement his own logic of DoSomething. This could be usefull if you have the same code being reused in derived classes.

```
    public abstract class CarRepository : ICarRepository
    {
        private string _model;
        private string _colour;

        protected CarRepository(string model, string colour) {
            _model = model;
            _colour = colour
        }

        public string Get(GUID id)
        {
            return id.ToString();
        }

        public absctract void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special); // Force all derived classes to implement this method

       protected virtual void DoSomethingBase(ref ISpecial special) {
            special = special.AddFields(Rego, ModelNumber)
        }
    }

public class BigCarRepository : CarRepository 
{
    public ICarRepository _carRepository { get; set; }

    public BigCarRepository(ICarRepository carRepository) : base (pass_the_model, pass_the_colour)
    {
        _carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    public override void DoSomething(ref ISpecial special) {
        DoSomethingBase(ref special); // if you need some base class logic
        special = special.AddFields(SpecialOffer, OptionPack);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a 'There is no suitable method to override' error in BigCarRepository

Comment: I get a 'There is no suitable method to override' error in BigCarRepository. I believe the CarRepository should be changed to abstract class as well. Otherwise the abstract DoSomething method will have an error of abstract-method-in-non-abstract-class

Comment: Yes, you're right. CarRepository should be abstract . But BigCarRepository should derive from that.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think you only need and want to implement the interface.  i've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @Yves Israel , i think @vins want to implement `CarRepository`s `DoSomething` member inside `BigCarRepository` but he dont want to inherit `CarRepository`

Comment: Yes, i got that. That's why i've added the ICarRepository implementation on BigCarRepository.